# add color to specific words in a txt.file

Tags: colors, highlight, txt

I am writing vhdl-code on visual studio code on a regular txt.file. So when I am writing, only text is written with no colors or anything. I am regularly using certain specifik words very often, such as: if, when, process e.t.c. Therefore I want to be able to have a certain color for certain words. I want for example that whenever I write: "if", if will turn blue. Or whenever I write: "begin" it should turn green.

How is this possible? Are there for example any extensions in VScode?

I don't know. I am new to VScode so any help would be appritiated!